# Is there any way to view the currently mapped keys in Vim?

Tags: vim

Basically, I'd like to view all of the keys maps made in the current buffer by all of plugins, vimrc, etc, in the current buffer. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Try `:help index` to see the VIM's __default__ key bindings. (Credit to Von and Lqueryvg)

Comment: If you're using [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) (neovim) then you can use `:Telescope keymaps` to view/fuzzy search them. Or if you use [whichkey](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) you can navigate keymaps through a menu.

Comment: @artfulrobot It seems like you accidentally linked to Telescope twice instead of linking to whichkey. Is this the right link: [github.com/folke/which-key.nvim](https://github.com/folke/which-key.nvim).  5 months since you posted that and I'm the first to mention it.

Comment: Without a doubt @artfulrobot has the MVP comment here.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

You can do that with the `:map` command. There are also other variants.

- `:nmap` for normal mode mappings
- `:vmap` for visual mode mappings
- `:imap` for insert mode mappings

The above list is not complete. Typing `:help map` in Vim will give you more info.

Comment: Just for clarify, I believe `:map`, as the original question asks, just shows mappings made by plugins, vimrc, etc. If you want to see the default key bindings in vim, use `:index`

Comment: @Von, you perhaps mean `:help index`.

Comment: these only give you the user-defined mappings, not the built-in (default) bindings

Comment: Is it possible to write them to a file to review them later?

Comment: @AntonDaneyko You can use https://github.com/AndrewRadev/bufferize.vim for that purpose.

Comment: The result is huge, could I `grep` or search (`/`) on their output?

Comment: When. I use `:map`, it shows me one screen's worth but won't allow me to scroll down to see the rest. How can I see all of the mappings?

Comment: Is there a way to launch vim, run this, dump the output to stdout, and exit vim?  I was hoping `vim +":nmap | :q"` would work but that's not the way to use vim.

Answer (score 134):

```
:redir! > vim_keys.txt
:silent verbose map
:redir END
```

This outputs the shortcuts, with where they were defined, to a text file.

Comment: I believe that you meant to use the `:redir` command, not the `:remap` command.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! Finally found that MacVim was remapping my <A-Up> command. Fixed by adding let macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement = 1

Comment: It is worth to note that `vim_keys.txt` file is located in working directory which can be checked by running `:pwd`.

Comment: This is great but doesn't capture insert and  command mode mappings, to see everything use :redir! >> vim_keys.txt :silent verbose map :silent verbost map! :redir END

Comment: @BrittonKerin: That sounds useful, but I'm having a hard time reading those steps because of the lack of delimiters. Can you put inverted commas (\`), AKA 'back ticks', around the commands, please, so they `look` `like` `this`, or ideally, submit a separate answer, so you'll get some credit as well? Cheers.

Answer (score 66):

In addition to answers about `:map` with no arguments: do not miss its verbose form (`:verbose map`) which shows where the mapping(s) was defined (see `:help map-verbose`).

Answer (score 17):

Quite simply, just run the `:map`  variants with no arguments.

```
:map
:imap
:vmap
```

Answer (score 16):

`:map` and its friends are the key, `:verbose` adds info and `:redir` allow post-search refinement.

They are a perfect mix to show what command is bind to what shortcut and viceversa, but if you want to search some keys and avoid temp files whenever you need to search mappings, take a look to [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) and `:Verbose` command.

It is a wrapper on `:verbose` to show result in a preview window.

this way you can search whatever you want inside results without using temp files

type `:Verbose map` and use <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> as usual.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to save session to a file and then edit this file as it contains all the mappings and settings.

`:mks[ession] [file]`   - Write a Vim script that restores the current editing
            session.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install this plug like this:
   `Plug 'https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease'`
2. What to know what `<M-C-F10>`(my own mapping) does?
   try this

```
:Verbose nmap <M-C-F10> |  omap <M-C-F10> | vmap <M-C-F10> | imap <M-C-F10> | cmap <M-C-F10> | tmap <M-C-F10>
```

put it in a function:

```
            func! Leo_keymap(keys)
                exe "verbose map " . a:keys
                exe "verbose map! " . a:keys
                exe "verbose tmap " . a:keys

                " 不好 / not good:
                    " exe "verbose nmap " . a:keys
                    " exe "verbose omap " . a:keys
                    " exe "verbose vmap " . a:keys
                    " exe "verbose imap " . a:keys
                    " exe "verbose cmap " . a:keys
                    " exe "verbose tmap " . a:keys
                " 不行 / not work
                    " exe "Verbose map " . a:keys  . <Bar> . "verbose map! " . a:keys . <Bar> .  "verbose tmap " . a:keys
            endfunc

        cnoreabbrev <expr> map   getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'map'          ? 'Verbose call Leo_keymap("")<left><left>'                       :   'map'
                " 不行 / not work
                    " command! -nargs=* Map :new<CR>:put = Vim_out('call Leo_keymap(input())')
                " 不行 / not work
                    " :put = Vim_out("call Leo_keymap('ls')")

        " may be take placed by the above line
            cnoreabbrev <expr> nmap  getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'nmap'          ? 'Verbose map'                       :   'map'
            cnoreabbrev <expr> imap  getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'imap'         ? 'Verbose imap'                      :   'imap'
            cnoreabbrev <expr> cmap  getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'cmap'         ? 'Verbose cmap'                      :   'cmap'
            cnoreabbrev <expr> tmap  getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'tmap'         ? 'Verbose tmap'                      :   'tmap'
```

---

old content, may be useless:

```
func! Leo_keymap(keys)
    exe "verbose map " . a:keys
    exe "verbose map! " . a:keys
    exe "verbose tmap " . a:keys
    " exe "Verbose map " . a:keys  . <Bar> . "verbose map! " . a:keys . <Bar> .  "verbose tmap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose nmap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose omap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose vmap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose imap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose cmap " . a:keys
    " exe "verbose tmap " . a:keys
endfunc

command! -nargs=* Map :call Leo_keymap(<q-args>)
```

now `:Map d` gets:

```
n  dL          * v$hhd
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/plug_wf.vim line 712
n  df          * ggdG
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/clipboard_regis.vim line 250
n  dB          * %dab
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/clipboard_regis.vim line 230
n  d"          * da"
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/clipboard_regis.vim line 212
n  dw          * diw
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/clipboard_regis.vim line 211
n  d'          * :call DoubleAsSingle()<CR>da'
        Last set from ~/dotF/cfg/nvim/clipboard_regis.vim line 195
No mapping found
No mapping found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So far, I don't know how to combine this with :Verbose .....