# How to see what mapping for a particular key in vim?

Tags: vim, mapping

I would like to know what `<leader>a` is mapped to in my vim.
Is there a command to know this?

Comment: Here a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642746/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-currently-mapped-keys-in-vim

Comment: @Joyas: None of the answers were specific to my question. i.e., knowing the map for a particular prefix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:map <leader>a` to get a list of all mappings having that specific prefix.

from `:h :map`

```
        List all key mappings for the modes where the map
        command applies.  Note that ":map" and ":map!" are
        used most often, because they include the other modes.
```

Comment: Don't for get `:verbose` will tell you where the mapping was last defined. e.g. `:verbose map <leader>a`. See `:h :map-verbose`. You can also supply a mode to narrow down your results as well. e.g. for normal mode do `:verbose nmap <leader>a`. For more help see `:h map-listing`.

Comment: @PeterRincker using `:verbose map` gives me message "Last set from Lua" with no path or anything. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ZenVentzi I am not familiar with such a message. My best guess is you are using Neovim and this mapping is possibly handled with Lua. I am sorry, I can not be more helpful. If you do find a way to query/debug a mapping in Neovim please share

Comment: To see file and line number information `Last set from Lua`, you'll need to run in the verbose mode (`nvim -V1`). See https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/23719