# Vim: How do you know what a key stroke does in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to get Vim to tell you what it did so you can look things up?

For example, I am trying to get better at navigating with vim and I noticed that when I press `j` I go down a row, but if I press `shift+j` it removes the line break at the end of the current line (or something like that).

`shift+k` however has no such behavior and `shift+h` seems to take me to the top of the current window while `shift+l` takes me to the bottom.

What I'm looking for is some way to understand *what* these movements are called so that I might be able to understand how to configure them / learn more about their behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642746/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-currently-mapped-keys-in-vim

Comment: Otherwise, try `:help J`.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking for is some way to understand what these movements are called so that I might be able to understand how to configure them / learn more about their behavior.

You are attacking the problem from the wrong end.

Learn Vim instead of trying random stuff:

1. If you didn't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It's a hands-on tutorial that will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. This is not a novel, go at your own pace and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: Thanks @romainl - agreed! I guess I'm not _just_ trying random stuff. Instead, I'm finding that these behaviors are happening when I was expecting other things to happen. I will work through `vimtutor` again. Appreciate the reminder!

Comment: Learning properly will free you from those false expectations.